# CSS Overflow: Hide it but keep text in it selectable

Tags: css, overflow

Basically, I need the overflow to behave like "auto", but hiding the scrollbar.

If I use "hidden" I cannot select the text beyond the limit.

Comment: So, sort of like an input box? I don't think that's possible without using an `<input>` tag directly.

Comment: More like an iframe.  I'd like to include html markup on it, like links and different text colors.

Answer (score 1):

try using something like this applied to the DIV that you want to control with scrolling.

```
#foo {
 height: 100px;
 overflow-y; scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

If you really want to hide the scrollbar, then replace it with JS or CSS for a blank image?